how can I stretch the image full with same quality?
you see at the right and and the left the image is white not full stretched. How can I stretch it with good quality ?
code:
.bg {
  background-image: url('/app/assets/bg.jpeg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: calc(100vh - 196px);
  background-position: top;
}



You are using contain. Are you just looking for background-size: cover?

@SyndRain I have another background image where left and right are words and text, if I use cover then the text goes outer size and I dont see the text only half

How do you cover the whitespace without streching then? You need to either stretch the image without maintaining the ratio, or stretch the image while cropping the overflow part. Sounds like there are multiple images with possibily different ratio? Or am I misunderstanding something?

@wepro01 Could you add the text as text over the background image instead of making the text part of the image?

You can use background-size: coverfor that, but this will result in the top and/or bottom part of the image being cut off in the situation you are showing in your screenshot (also depending on the background-position setting).
It depends on the image and on the screen proportions (width versus height of the area in which the image is shown) whether that works well - you'll have to try.
The best thing would be to set the height relative to the width so you always get the same width/heigth ratio, using vw units for it.

You are all right there.  Just need to replace background-size: contain; width background-size: cover;.
Even if that does not make, then you can try aspect ratio.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url('https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1664304752635-3e0d8d8185e3');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: calc(100vh - 196px);
  background-position: top;
}
<div class='bg'></div>



Hope this helps.
